# Networking scenario for multiple virtual machines on a host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, freebsd

I have a physical machine hosting 3 virtual machines and im using virtualbox. 2 VM's are simple machines that just need to ping each other (lets call them G1 and G2) whereas the 3rd VM has openvswitch (lets call it VM_OVS).

Imagine this scenario:

I'd like that G1 and G2 ping each other using the openvswitch bridge residing in the VM_OVS. All the machines can be on the same subnet, there is no need for them to have access to the internt. I just need to test openvswitch and see if it works properly in this scenario.

What network scenario am i setting up? And more specifically how do i set it up? What Virtualbox settings do i need.

I have done an experiment similar to this but with 2 guests communicating with each other through openvswitch residing on the host. So you can see the the scenario described above is slightly different. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It sounds like you want a Host-Only adapter (if you want to be able to access the machine from your host)

Comment: If you don't want to access them from your host, then you want Internal Networking.

Comment: Just create an Internal Network and assign it to the three machines, then treat VM_OVS as you did your physical host.

Comment: as to your 3rd comment, I can't treat VM_OVS as the host as G1 & G2 are not inside VM_OVS! thats the problem!

Comment: But assign them all to a single Internal Network, then you will see the three machines on a single network.

Comment: ok, ill try. do you have any experiecnce with openvswitch?

Comment: Nope.  Only networking with VirtualBox, but this should give you a similar network-side setup as you had before.